# What type of program is this called?

Tags: localhost

I've been searching and searching and asking around, but I can't find an answer. There are programs that seem to be able to act as servers on localhost while they run and produce pages in memory that allow the user to interact with this program.

Examples of them are: "Mediacoder" and "K9 Web Protect".

Please tell me what kind of programming I need to lookup in order to accomplish the same tasks as these programs. That way I can actually have a direction when I'm googling it in C# or Java or whatever. All answers are welcome on this one.

Comment: Ummmm... based on my quick glance, Mediacoder, looks like a typical windows forms type application that from what you've said, also runs a server in the background (although this might be a different binary).  It's kind of hard to know 'what type of program' means.  Which task are you trying to achieve?  Listening on a port?  Showing stuff to the user?

Answer (score 2):

There exists no special name for desktop applications that also provide a web frontend.

Comment: Okay, see that's what I need. I just needed to know what it was called. It's referred to as a "wweb frontend"? That's what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for something like this:

[Embedded Web Server in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155161/embedded-web-server-in-net)