# Is WCF an appropriate technology to develop an embedded web server?

Tags: .net, wcf, http

We need to embed an HTTP Web Server in a C# 4.0 application and were wondering if WCF is a suitable technology for this purpose?

Comment: Please tell us more, what is it about, can you not use IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good suggestions for a .NET embedded web server here:

[Embedded Web Server in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155161/embedded-web-server-in-net)

To answer your question, WCF can be setup as a web server, and there are [examples out](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2008/10/23/mini-web-server-using-wcf) there of people doing it.  WCF can listen for HTTP requests on port 80, and you can support REST using the WCF REST Starter Kit.  However, you are sacrificing some of the capabilities of a more full-featured web server such as redundancy and fault tolerance.

When you say that this is "embedded" web server, in what context will this run?

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a much higher lever of abstraction than a web server. Try [Cassini](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: @ QrystaL: We are familiar with Cassini. Let's see if others agree with your assessment that WCF is inappropriate. Thanks.